# How to read multiple object from JTable and store them in a text file?

Tags: java, swing, serialization, jtable

I have a `JTable` & I can read only one object from this table and it can store one data.

I can only get users info from the table and it stores only one row of data. How can I read multiple data from this table and also store it in a text file as serialized object?

Here's my code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==submitButton && 
            fullNameText.getText().isEmpty() || 
            EmailAddressText.getText().isEmpty()||
            passportNumberText.getText().isEmpty()||
            dobText.getText().isEmpty()) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill up the form first");
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == submitButton){
        String gender;
        if(male.isSelected()) {
            gender = "Male";
        }
        else {
            gender ="Female";
        }
                examinee = new Examinee(
                    fullNameText.getText(),
                    EmailAddressText.getText(),
                    passportNumberText.getText(),
                    gender,
                    dobText.getText()
                    );
        //alertMessageLabel.setVisible(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Successfully Registered for the exam.");
        //form = new RegisterForm();
        try {
            writeData(examinee);
            readData();
        }
        catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        fullNameText.setText("");
        EmailAddressText.setText("");
        passportNumberText.setText("");
        male.setSelected(true);
        dobText.setText("");
   }
}//End Of Submit Button

//Created writeData and readData method for write and read data
void writeData(Examinee examinee) throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
    objectOut.writeObject(examinee);
    objectOut.close();
}

void readData() {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
        Examinee readExaminee = (Examinee)  objectIn.readObject();
        objectIn.close();
        rows[0]= readExaminee.getFullName();
        rows[1]= readExaminee.getEmailAddress();
        rows[2]= readExaminee.getPassportNumber();
        rows[3]= readExaminee.getGender();
        rows[4]= readExaminee.getDob();
        model.addRow(rows);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you add your entity directly to the table? The detour via the file is not necessary.

Comment: I highly recommend the JTable tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: Put ***all*** the rows of the table into a collection (such as an array or `ArrayList`) and serialize the collection. There are potentially other ways to do it, but that is the simplest.